# measure two different (vector) signal similarity

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, similarity

i'm suffering in finding a good way to compare (measure) the similarity between two different signals. I do not want to find the time-delay of one signal to another, but I want to see how are they similar to each other.
For example, i have the follow two signals, let say s1 ans s2. the two signals look very similar, however in one signal there is a sudden jump which results in the second part of the signal (also the dominant one) has an offset compared to the first part.

[image]

When I use the cross-covariance as well as cross-correlation, it gives me a very poor result, namely:

```
xcov(s1, s2, 0, 'coeff') ----> 0.2153
```

However looking at the two signals, we can see that they're very similar. In fact if taking the cross-covariance of the two signals only from sample (50->the end of the signal), the result is very good:

```
   xcov(s1(50:280), s2(50:280), 0, 'coeff') ----> 0.9666
```

So i guess the problem is due to the big jumping at around the sample 25 (in the red signal).

My questions are:

- How to overcome the above problem ?
- Is cross-covariance (correlation) a good way to measure the similarity between two signals?
- Is there other way to do this ?

Thanks a lot. I really appreciate any help from you!

Comment: would you consider measuring the similarity between the *gradient* of the signals?

Comment: Can you use a moving-average filter to calculate a mean value over a short range, then subtract that from the signal en then check for similarities?

Comment: If you consider that jump as being an outlier, you can try outlier removing methods like RANSAC (just a thought...)

Comment: I think you can use a kind-of moving average filter anyway, to check similarities between small portions of the signal. Possibly removing the mean of each portion to overcome the jump problem, then use cross correlation on each portion.

Comment: Thank you @A. Visser:
 I did try that, and it gives a more promising result. 
Just wonder, is there other method for comparing the similarity between two different signals ? Cause for me, cross-correlation is kind of the simplest way to do, however it does not reflects the true similarity.
Because even if i only compare small parts of the signals, I need to know how small should they be, otherwise I don't think it gives good result.

Comment: Thank you @Shai: I'm not so familiar with the concept of gradient of vectores, I'll try to have a deeper look into it, and maybe inform the result later

Comment: Thank you @ Parag S. Chandakkar:
I'll will search for this RANSAC algorithm

Comment: @bienle if you `diff` your vectors you get new vectors (one sample shorter) which then you can compare using correlation etc.

Comment: @bienle . what was your final approach to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You probably should look into robust correlation coefficients as well. There is quite some literature and research around. However when I recreated your signals, I might have found a solution for you. As the signals are quite stable except at one point there is a simple trick.

We can recreate the signal with `s1 = [s1(1) cumsum(diff(s1))];`. From here the idea is simple. We want to ignore the big jump. Therefore we have to limit the maximal value from `diff(s1)`. It is done by:

`s1_robust = [s1(1) cumsum(sign(diff(s1)).*min(abs(diff(s1)),1))];`.

I chose 1 in the `min(s1,1)` part kind of arbitrary. You might want to set this to some factor of the signals standard deviation.

Here is the full code I used to analyse your problem.

> ```
> clc, clear all, close all
>
> signal = cos([0:0.1:20]);
> s1 = signal + rand(1,201);
> s2 = signal + rand(1,201);
> s2(50:end) = s2(50:end)-8;
>
> s1_robust = [s1(1) cumsum(sign(diff(s1)).*min(abs(diff(s1)),1))];
> s2_robust = [s2(1) cumsum(sign(diff(s2)).*min(abs(diff(s2)),1))];
> corr        = corrcoef(s1,s2)
> corr_robust = corrcoef(s1_robust,s2_robust)
>
>  figure
>  plot(s1);
>  hold on;
>  plot(s2);
>
>  figure
>  plot(cumsum(sign(diff(s1)).*min(abs(diff(s1)),1)));
>  hold on;
>  plot(cumsum(sign(diff(s2)).*min(abs(diff(s2)),1)));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looking on your data, I would strongly suggest going to frequency domain (using DFT for instance). Comparison in the frequency domain should find the similarity between the two suggest signals.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the area between those two curves. The curves are similar if the area is small, not so similar if the area is big.

Edit: To deal with the curves "jump" and DC offset cases, the area between the two curves should be caculated after doing [ICP (Iterative Closest Point)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) alignment.

Comment: Thanks @ Hesham Eraqui.
I don't think so, first of all, the jumping would cause a serious difference in the result. And also due to the noise, or DC offsets, the area between two curves can be much larger than it suppose to be.